# Ubuntu Java Application Not finding the command javac when java 11 is confirmed installed

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am trying to run a java application, but its saying javac not found. When I did install java by using the following command:

> sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless

It's in my path as I can run java command fine. I'm not sure why it isn't seeing the javac command. What am I missing after installing openjdk-11 java ?

[image]

Comment: Try run `java -version` and send output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have installed the Java Runtime Environment (JRE): `openjdk-11-jre` which allows you to run java software.

And should install the Java Developer Kit (JDK) in order to compile code:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```